# I dont understand error "definition of implicity-declared 'Clothing::Clothing()'

Tags: c++, oop, constructor

**The question:**

Why is the following error happening?

> definition of implicity-declared 'Clothing::Clothing()

**The context:**

As an assignment I have to do constructors, destructors and methods in a class Clothing. I'm having a problem when I try to define the constructor in *clothing.cpp*. I have read that the problem is because I did not declare the constructor in *clothing.h*, but I think how I have done it, it's declared. I have no clue where the problem lies.

**My code:**

clothing.h:

```
#ifndef CLOTHING_H_
#define CLOTHING_H_
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Clothing {
private:
    int gender;
    int size;
    string name;

public:
    Clothing();
    Clothing(const Clothing &t);
    Clothing(int gender, int size, string name);
    ~Clothing();
    int getGender();
    int getSize();
    string getName();
    void setGender(int gender1);
    void setSize(int size1);
    void setName(string name1);
    void print();
    void toString();
};

#endif /* CLOTHING_H_ */
```

clothing.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "clothing.h"
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

Clothing::Clothing() :
        gender(1), 
        size(1), 
        name("outofstock") {

}

Clothing::Clothing(const Clothing& t) :
        gender(t.gender), 
        size(t.size), 
        name(t.name) {
}

Clothing::Clothing(int gender, int size, string name) {

}

int Clothing::getGender() {
    return gender;
}

int Clothing::getSize() {
    return size;
}

string Clothing::getName() {
    return name;
}

void Clothing::setGender(int gender1) {
    gender = gender1;
}

void Clothing::setSize(int size1) {
    size = size1;
}

void Clothing::setName(string name1) {
    name = name1;
}

void Clothing::print() {
    cout << name << "  " << gender << "  " << size << endl;
}

void Clothing::toString() {
    stringstream ss;
    ss << name << "  " << gender << "  " << size;
    cout << ss.str();
}
```

Errors: **\src\clothing.cpp:7:21: error: definition of implicitly-declared 'Clothing::Clothing()'**

**\src\clothing.cpp:14:37: error: definition of implicitly-declared 'Clothing::Clothing(const Clothing&)'**

Comment: Why not define it in your header?

Comment: Please extract a [mcve]. This will probably be just a single file. As a new user, also visit [tour] and [ask].

Comment: @Mini Following the assigment instructions that specifies that I have to have .cpp file, and how we have been taught in class is defining it in .cpp

Comment: Also, is there an `#endif` at the end of your header?

Comment: This isn't the real code. The real code does not have declarations for those constructors.

Comment: I agree with @user207421. If using an IDE or even just VSCode or Notepad++, make sure the files you are editing are actually where they are supposed to be.

Comment: @Mini Eclipse automatically added that. I dont understand what you are trying to say with user207421

Comment: @Mini is agreeing with me. If Eclipse automatically add that, why isn't it in this post? All this confirms my diagnosis.

Comment: @user207421 sorry, didnt see i left that out when i copied the code. Edited the post. Do I also need to add .cpp where main function is?

Comment: Please copy and paste your actual code. This is not correct. `#endif` should be at the end

Comment: Please, post full error from the compiler, also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is: you declared a destructor but you didn't define it. Add a definition for the destructor or define it as default:

```
#ifndef CLOTHING_H_
#define CLOTHING_H_
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Clothing {
private:
    int gender;
    int size;
    string name;

public:
    Clothing();
    Clothing(const Clothing &t);
    Clothing(int gender, int size, string name);
    ~Clothing() = default; // <-- add a default destructor
    int getGender();
    int getSize();
    string getName();
    void setGender(int gender1);
    void setSize(int size1);
    void setName(string name1);
    void print();
    void toString();

};
#endif /* CLOTHING_H_ */
```

After fixing this your code snippet works: [tio.run](https://tio.run/##nVRNb9swDD1Xv4JIgCIpsmS9xlkvPbQDhu7Q3QtVURJhjmRIdAes6P56Rn34Q4m7rjUMyHziI58pUqKqPomS6@3hMFYbvZYbuP72/cft17ubh9sHNiZAaZljSouyXktYObRKb696iDKESb6/Yqx2tAea76WruJDgcF0wRrmcg@vS4M5vP7PKqieOcsmAHqURtpJU2KK1nfotoxXThZAUqaofSyUir4k3mRa5LYx22KU7x2OHLuOszTbrZ0qEP10K@AJUFV6XWPRE402I0ihI4D2Fa6AUlNA7itugT0atwbX0Ts/lkUMI1Ug83gwRe6qzfSqxxiwfmvvg60H2UrAxZVQbWFz0DxouFmzwaP/VAO6N82/KuFz2CrqExYK@HdD7ayetBOXLBFyDtNbYINw/sTKTy@kMWsyXI0d8zsnI1Gg2Do34OZpSn7GXweR5g5wDvl8NzuPHiSic@@VEGc5DX5EmkkQl14b6iebCclRGw56j2Ek3oPXtXvWScSeBBaHgxdMhfizUM7BQNL/dReg1Ov2A/ycrsba6HdshRpyC3D@ONXmnpBkhDkhOiGNPhNDBnfvw7CRuNGliE/5KgKPZSmRvEDVgrxBP5y5xvUHcgA1x00wmb0HNCqtVZNE6AnppTfJ7SNBEK22UQ3G7yW5@IphxKsG5dBW5/89WZAqdm1Msf2@kg95zpUOys/aWFQU7S4f2mfwOh78)

If you have more problems with your code, the problems are outside of your provided code snippet.